# Set Anchor tag width

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have tried several answer here and have not been able to find what is going on.

I am making a wordpress site, I have some knowledge but I am not an expert and I havent had success in accomplishing what I am looking for.

Here is the deal, I am trying to place social icons in the footer of a website (wordpress, with a theme). When I place the images, it looks like it is intended to do:

[The left column shows the icons properly aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSsnl.png)

As soon as I start placing the Anchor Tags like this (only one of the icons has the anchor tags):

```
<div>
    <a href="[full link to your Facebook page]"> 
        <img title="Facebook" src="http://fundacionhonrarlavida.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/1453371609_Facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="35" height="35" />
    </a>
    <img title="Twitter" src="http://fundacionhonrarlavida.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/1453371295_twitter_social_media_online.png" alt="Twitter" width="35" height="35" />
    <img title="YouTube" src="http://fundacionhonrarlavida.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/1453416978_youtube.png" alt="YouTube" width="35" height="35" />
    <img title="LinkedIn" src="http://fundacionhonrarlavida.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/1453417011_linkedIN.png" alt="LinkedIn" width="35" height="35" />
    <img title="Mail" src="http://fundacionhonrarlavida.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/1453417082_mail.png" alt="Mail" width="35" height="35" />      
</div>
```

The one that has a link ocuppies the whole row and moves the others to the next one.

I tried inspecting the moved Icon and realized per this image, that is the anchor property thats taking the whole space, as the image is the right size:

[Is the Anchor tag that is taking the whole space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STMnD.png)

Now I have tried so many things, in the a img a at ccs, i placed display in block, inline-block, and I always get the same results.

Jus as a test, I tried to use a plugin for social icons and the icons were also displaying vertically.

Here is the css regarding the img:

```
a img, a {
    display: inline-block 
    border: none; 
    outline:none; 
} 
a {
    outline:none; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color:#525252;
}
```

I also, created a class .footer a, where I specified the size of the anchor, but it didnt help.

Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is pretty hard to help you out with when you only have supplied an image and a little bit of code.  That footer has a lot going on and it could be a few things causing your issue.  Would you be able to give more code, or do a jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: In console view, start checking and unchecking CSS rules until you find the one that is causing the problem.

Comment: But to guess, I will say you may also just want to set the margin and padding to 0.

Comment: Try add semicolon here: a img, a {display: inline-block-->;<-- border: none; outline:none;

Comment: Hi... sorry for not providing more details as so I am not sure exactly what would be needed.. and I know that posting the whole code would be lazy. It it os regarding the Width of the "a" property. As the footer is composed of widget areas!

Answer (score 0):

try with using within "inline element": 
style="position: absolute;"

or add a class in the CSS with following position:
position: absolute;

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the following style rule:

```
.textwidget > div > a {
display: inline-block;
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I understand this and why... can this be placed anywhere on the styles.css file?

Comment: It's pretty specific in that it applies _only_ to anchors which are direct children of `div`s which are direct children of an element with the class `textwidget`, so probably yes. The more specific a declaration, the less it matters where it sits in the cascade.

Comment: Without seeing more code to be able to diagnose the issue correctly, I would guess that the style declaration _is_ working but is then being overwritten by another rule with higher priority or lower down the cascade. Can you post the url of the relevant page below and I will have a look at it and see which style rule (or rules) are overriding the one above.